# Handle the incoming emails using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

**Problem**: Handle the incoming emails using vbscript.

**Outlook Version**: Outlook 2000

**Description**: I cannot use VBA for this as I believe  Outlook 2000 doesn't let you run a VBA script from the rules wizard and hence I have to use the `Run a Program | VBScript` method.

**What I know**: I know how to handle email from VBA like this

```
Sub Sample(MyMail As MailItem)
    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

    '~~> Rest of the code

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

I also know how to run the vbscript on the email which is **already in** the inbox. To run a vbscript in OL2000, you have to use `Run A Program` and point it to the vbs file. The `Run A Script` is not available in OL2000.

**What I do not know**: And this is where I need help. How to get the mail object which has not hit the mail inbox in VBS. Once I get the object then I can do the rest of the necessary operations.

Comment: Sorry I'm confused: `How to get the mail object which has not hit the mail inbox in VBS` if it hasn't reached the Inbox, as far as Outlook is concerned, it doesn't exist.

Comment: @bonCodigo: just drop me ur email here http://www.siddharthrout.com/contact/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that OL2000 cannot run a VBA macro from a rule, if [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324568) is to be believed.

Here's how I handle incoming emails. It does use VBA but as far as I know, there isn't a way to do so in VBScript.

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Application_Startup() 
  Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
  Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
  Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set Items = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items 
End Sub
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 

  On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item 
    '~~> do something with the new message here
  End If
ProgramExit: 
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
  Resume ProgramExit 
End Sub
```

This code should be pasted into the ThisOutlookSession module, then Outlook should be restarted.

Comment: Thanks JP, I know how to do it via VBA but my client specifically wants vbs LOL. So there is no way I can get the mail object which has not hit the mail inbox in VBS?

Comment: `Run a Script` is not available in `Outlook 2000` as the link correctly mentions but we have an option of running a VBScript when an email comes in using `Run a Program` I just tested it with a `Hello World` vbs which ran fine. So now in the VBS, I need to write a code which will get the mail object.

Comment: @SiddharthRout Oh boy, a client polluting the goal by requiring a specific implementation. The fact that they are still running Outlook 2000 is a huge red flag IMO. If they know better, why can't they implement it themselves? That link in my answer shows how the VBA I posted can be used in Outlook 2000. I fail to see why VBScript is preferable over VBA in this case. VBA is so far superior, not to mention I cannot locate any sample VBScript that uses the `Run A Program` functionality.

Comment: `That link in my answer shows how the VBA I posted can be used in Outlook 2000.` Let me try and convince them :)

Comment: He agreed :) Thanks for the help. One interesting thing I would like to share though. I wanted to trap the email in the code based on the sender's email address and realized that there was no property like `.SenderEmailAddress` in OL2000!!! Had to set the name in the address book and then used the `.SenderName` to trap the email. In the end everything went off well :) Thanks again.

Comment: Just for enhancing my knowledge, if you ever comes across a vbs code which lets me handle the incoming email, then I would definitely love to see it :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Excellent! If do find such a code I'll let you know.